# What is an 8.5 x 4.5in bread pan in UK lb based pan sizes?

Tags: bread, pan, conversion

An American relative has asked for an 8.5x4.5in bread pan for Christmas, but UK pan sizes are by weight: 1lb loaf, 2lb loaf, etc.

How much dough would you put into an 8x4 (or 8.5x4.5) pan?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately sorting bread pans by loaf weight is very vague. A *1lb* light and fluffy white sandwich bread might have about the same size as a *2lb* heavy, dense wholegrain or rye bread. Also, do you expect your bread to rise really high over the rim or should that be more of a limit? In short, the size of "a 1lb bread" depends a lot on the kind of bread you have in mind.

A quick Internet check of pan dimensions from various manufactureres confirms that there is no standard size, it seems they vary by up to 50% in volume.

So if your relative's wish list states a pan of a certain *size*, I suggets you go shopping equipped with a meassuring tape instead of looking for a certain "pound value".

---

Side note: Most 2lb pans are a tad bigger that the requested size and 1lb ones a bit smaller, but I found [one](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Brand-New-Insulated-Resistant-Cleaning/dp/B00JKPOWPK/) sold in the UK by Williams Sonoma (what a coincidence!) that seems to have exactly the sought-for dimensions.

Comment: Thanks! Found the pan and lots of useful baking knowledge :)

Answer (score 1):

**Rectangular**

11 x 7 x 2 inches   6 cups

13 x 9 x 2 inches   14 cups

*28 x 18 x 5 cm     1.4 liters*

33 x 23 x 5 cm      3.3 liters

**Loaf**

*8 x 4 x 2 1/2 in.  4 cups*

8 1/2x4 1/2x2 1/2   6 cups

9 x 5 x 3 inches    8 cups

20 x 10 x 6 cm      948 ml

21 x 11 x 6 cm      1.4 liters

23 x 13 x 8 cm      1.9 liters

That is the best I can do...

3 1/2 cups of flour is approximately one pound.

Further research and some measuring ...

A 1lb Loaf Pan will have a volume of around 1 litre (or 4 Cups).

You can assume that a Cup is around 240ml, hence the 4 cups to the litre I mentioned above.

Comment: The volume of yeast breads will be about twice the volume of flour since you rise the dough to double before baking.

Comment: Also you add water - I'm not sure that the volume of the dough pre-rise is the same as the volume of the flour.